# Trying to translate an SFX but the characters look confusing

Tags: questions, handwriting, learning, sound-symbolism

[image]

I'm really bad at reading the characters when they're written in a different way, these three ones are the ones I think are in the highlight but I would like to be sure. m(_ _)m Someone kind enough to help me get it right?
| きやっ... |
キやっ... |
キウっ... |

Comment: [We don't do translations/transcriptions](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/21657). The reddit r/translator subreddit is a great alternative.

Comment: I tend to keep it open because the letter in the middle is reasonably ambiguous with ゆ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `もわっ…`. It's a mimetic word that describes smoke, moisture, smell or something similar started to fill the atmosphere. This person seems to be sweating, so it may be describing the smelly moisture of sweat. Or maybe it's describing this person's "negative aura". Please see the context.

- [What does むわりと mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/67792/5010)

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm so stupid I missed the existence of も also, lol.