# What does むわって /muwatte means in this context?

Tags: grammar, meaning, expressions, japanese-to-english

I met this in a sentence that describe a sweet scent in the air, but don't understand this part

甘い香りが**むわって**漂ってきてる

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/67792/9831

Answer (score 3):

むわっ is a variant of an onomatopoeia [むわり](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/67792/9831).

(っ)て is a colloquial version of と.

So むわって means 「むわっ」と, or 「むわり」と.